# What is being referenced for this matrix?

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I was given the following code to use as part of an exercise. I am instructed to create a 3x3 matrix and assign specific values to it.

Here is the code:

```
void minput(int* m, int row, int col) {
/* assign 3X3 matrix to following value 
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
*/
    *(m+0) = 8;
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is what this piece of code `*(m+0) = 8;` is for. I know that adding a `*` in front of any variable means to "give me whatever is that the address".

What does the +0 do?

Comment: `+0` adds zero.  8, according to the comment that is in the code, is the value that should be in matrix position 0,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*(m+0) = 8` is the same as `m[0] = 8`, it dereferences the pointer to the first element then assigns to it the value `8`. In your code you represent the matrix via a one-dimensional array, so you probably want to index your `(i,j)` component as
`m+i*col + j` or, equivalently, `m[i*col+j]`, i.e. the line

```
*(m+i*col+j) = x // can also write is as m[i*col+j] = x
```

assigns `x` to the `(i,j)` component.

Comment: `col` is just the parameter you declared in `minput()`.

Comment: think about taking your matrix and reshaping it into a 1-dimensional array. Then you need to know how many columns the original matrix had, in order to be able to map the 1D array back to a matrix. So the index `(i,j)` in a matrix becomes the index `i*col + j` in a 1D array. This is called *row-major order*. You can also arrange the columns in a 1D array, and you'll have what is called *column-major order*. By default, `C`-style languages use raw-major order when dealing with matrices, i.e. a matrix is internally represented as a 1D array in row-major order.

Answer (score 4):

`*(m+0)` is equivalent to `m[0]`. So the whole statement is assigning `8` to `m[0]`.

Comment: What is the equivalent of m[0][1] using that format?

Comment: `((width - 1) * (x+1)) + y`

Answer (score 2):

it dereferences m (gives you the value at it)  I'm guessing it's + 0 so that you can add in different values and get the resulting part of the matrix

Arrays are contiguous in memory, so if you were to add 1 instead of 0, you would set the next value in the matrix to 8.

Comment: **no, no, no**, you don't need to add `sizeof(int)`, the pointer "knows" how to increment itself, since is of type `int*`. If you add `sizeof(int)` to `m` and say that e.g. `sizeof(int) = 4`, then you jump the pointer over 4 `int`s.

Comment: @vsoftco Haha oops, I've been doing mostly web-dev lately, the last time I used pointers was in assembly where you have to add the size of the data type your addressing.  Good catch!  Editing my post now.